# Converting Dataframe to Array, Hashtable

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, dataframe, hashtable

I have a Dataframe in this format. But want to convert it to the format in the mockup below, iterating for every Manager. Note that Interns are always Part-Time, and all the other roles are always Full-Time. Any help will be greatly appreciated!
[Dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3p9N3.png)

[mockup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0XOHh.png)

Comment: can you add `Dataframe` as `csv` file by uploading to any Cloud?..Gdrive/Onedrive add link here & also add code what you've tried upto now

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/vqauseiltczdc4z/Dataframe.csv?dl=0 https://www.dropbox.com/s/1aan0koo2mijr3u/Mockup.csv?dl=0

Answer (score 0):

I think this will help you.

```
    import pandas as pd

    def collect_names(series):
        return list(series.values)

    df = pd.read_csv(r'/content/Dataframe.csv')
    df = df.assign(name_with_role = lambda x: x['EMPLOYEE NAME']+' ('+ x['ROLE']+ ')')
    intermediate_dict = df.groupby(by=['MANAGER NAME', 'STATUS'], as_index=False)['name_with_role'].agg(collect_names).to_dict('records')
    output_dict = {}
    for i in intermediate_dict:
        if i['MANAGER NAME'] not in output_dict.keys():
            output_dict[i['MANAGER NAME']]= {i['STATUS']: i['name_with_role']} 
        else:
            output_dict[i['MANAGER NAME']].update({i['STATUS']: i['name_with_role']} )
    print(output_dict)
```

Comment: Thank you! This is getting close to what it should be. But I am not sure how to go further. I think perhaps a dictionary or hash table?

Comment: I added the new code to convert grouped object to dictionary

Comment: while this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please [include an explanation for your code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392712/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers), as that really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.